# Cross Platform Automation/Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, teamcity, cross-platform

I am writing a dotnetcore application which I hope to be cross platform.

I am using Teamcity server. I have three machines, Windows, Mac and Linux (Ubuntu).

I wondered if there is a way to test an application on all three platforms upon each commit?

I could then be alerted if the build/tests fail on any of the supported environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer here: https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206266939-Triggering-a-configuration-on-multiple-operating-systems?sort_by=created_at

It appears that this feature is not yet supported by TeamCity. Whilst this is not the answer I was looking for. It does answer my question.